# Google api php redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-4, google-plus, google-api-php-client

When using the following composer package `bitgandtter/google-api` for google php api client since I'm using it in combination with laravel 4 I get the following error `redirect_uri_mismatch`. My code looks like this(which is located under `app/lib` using the PSR-0 spec):

```
class Google {
    private $client;
    private $token;

    public function __construct($code)
    {   
        $this->client = new Google_Client();
        $this->client->setApplicationName("camelCaseD");

        $this->client->setClientId('SOMENUMBERS.apps.googleusercontent.com');
        $this->client->setClientSecret('PRECIOUS');
        $this->client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost:9000/auth/google');

        $this->client->authenticate($code);
    }
}
```

My routes are:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function()
{
    Route::post('google', function()
    {
        $postInput = file_get_contents('php://input');

        try
        {
            $google = new Google($postInput);
        } catch (Exception $e)
        {
            return Redirect::to('signin')->with('error', $e->getMessage());
        }
    });
});
```

I'm using the official google plus sign in button to log the user in then passing the authorization code to my server via `$.ajax()`.

Here's what my api console settings look like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got that similar error. To resolve mine, I went to google console and reset the secret. I also made sure the Authorized JavaScript origins was set to the correct address.

Answer (score -1):

http:// localhost :900/auth/google 
 is a directory or a page? 
Maybe if it is a directory, the final url is different (like http:// localhost :900/auth/google/index.php) and Google does a control between 2 string, but they are different.

Comment: are you familiar with the concept of routing and mod_rewrite with apache?